# Java Stream: how to pass Set to Stream.of() and call method on each elemnt?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i have such  old-style code:

```
        if (setContainer.getSet() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (SetElement setElement : setContainer.getSet()){
            if ("SomeString".equals(SetElement.getCode())) {
                return  setElement.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
```

i've tried this but it doesnt check if Set is null:

```
setContainer.getSet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(setValue ->  "SomeValue".equals(setElement.getCode()))
                    .map(SetElement::getValue)
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(null) ;
```

as i understand, i should use `Stream.of()`
but i dont understand how to perform code as above, because it always returns `Optional<Set<SetElement>>`

Comment: Why should you use `Stream.of()`?

Comment: as i undertand, it will check iset != null, or it won't?

Comment: I don't see that in [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-) to achieve this:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(setContainer.getSet())
    .flatMap(set -> set.stream()
        .filter(e ->  "SomeValue".equals(e.getCode()))
        .map(SetElement::getValue)
        .findAny())
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Sorry, you were right, Optional.flatMap returns an Optional.

Comment: will this return null if set == null or setElement == null ?

Comment: @Igor ~~It will return `null` in both cases~~. No wait, I'm distracted by the edit. It will return `null` if the set was null or if no element was found that satisfies the `filter`.

Comment: This is abuse of `Optional`. The existing `if(x = null)` works fine, as would a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to try to apply new tools when your existing tools work fine. So if you need a null check, keep checking it with `if`.

```
 set = setContainer.getSet();
 if(set == null) {
    return null;
 } else {
    return mapAndFilter(set);
 }
```

Or, with a ternary operator:

```
 Set<T> set = setContainer.getSet();
 return set == null ? null : mapAndFilter(set);
```

Now you can implement `mapAndFilter()` cleanly, accepting a `Map<T>` that's guaranteed not to be null, and returning a `Map<U>`. It may well make sense to implement `mapAndFilter()` using streams.

Introducing `Optional` to this just adds unnecessary objects, and unnecessary clutter to the code.

That said, it's better style to never pass nulls, so if you can enhance your `setContainer` so that it never returns null (maybe it can return an empty set?), that would be better.

It *may* be a good compromise to make `setContainer` supply `Optional<Set<T>>`. But even then, traditional techniques might be preferable to functional syntax:

```
 Optional<Set<T>> maybeSet = setContainer.getSet();

 return maybeSet.isPresent() ? mapAndFilter(maybeSet.get()) : null;
 // vs
 return maybeSet.isPresent() ? mapAndFilter(maybeSet.get()) : Optional.empty();
 // vs
 return maybeSet.map(mapAndFilterFunction); // might return empty Optional
 // vs
 return maybeSet.map(mapAndFilterFunction).orElse(null); // might return null;
```

In these `mapAndFilter()` is a method. `mapAndFilterFunction` is a `Function` defined as `Function<Set<T>,Set<U>> mapAndFilterFunction = s -> { ... };`

Comment: This is good but I would change `return set == null ? set : mapAndFilter(set);` to the following version with an explicit *null*: `return set == null ? null : mapAndFilter(set);`. The fact that `set` happens to be `null` at that point is sort of accidental to the logic of that line; you don't want to return a null *set* but a null *item* so I think it's clearer to just write `null` explicitly.

Comment: I want to try new tool, also this reduced code twice

Comment: +1, especially for saying that using Optional in this way "adds unnecessary objects and unnecessary clutter to the code." Also, if `getSet()` returns a Set, it's usually preferable for it to return an empty set than `Optional<Set<T>>` if there are no values to be returned.

Comment: @Igor trying new things is nice. Just don't use them in production code unless if they don't add value. And don't mistake shorter code for better code. `Optional` is useful for method return values in some cases. If you create an `Optional` then dereference it the same block, you're writing confusing code *and* creating a pointless object.